# How to send many emails via ASP.NET without delaying response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email

Following a specific action the user takes on my website, a number of messages must be sent to different emails. Is it possible to have a separate thread or worker take care of sending multiple emails so as to avoid having the response from the server take a while to return if there are a lot of emails to send?

I would like to avoid using system process or scheduled tasks, email queues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely spawn off a background thread in your controller to handle the emails asynchronously.

I know you want to avoid queues, but another thing i have done in the past is written a windows service that pulls email from a DB queue and processes it at certain intervals. This way you can separate the 2 applications if there is a lot of email to be sent.

Comment: Any preference towards a regular thread vs `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in many different ways, depending on how large your application is and what kind of reliability you want. Any of these ways should help you achieve what you want (in ascending order based on complexity):

- If you're using IIS SMTP Server or another mail server that supports a pickup directory option, you can go with that. With this option, instead of sending the emails directly, they are saved first in the pickup directory. Your call will immediately return after the email is saved in the pickup directory, so the user won't have to wait until the email is sent. On the other hand, the server will try to send the email as soon as it's saved in the pickup directory so it's almost immediate (just without blocking the call).
- You can use a background thread like described in other answers. You'll need to be careful with this option as the thread can end unexpectedly before it finishes its job. You'll need to add some code to make sure this works reliably (personally, I'd prefer not to use this option).
- Using a messaging queue server like MSMQ. This is more work and you probably should only look into this if you have a large scale application or have good reasons not to use the first option with the pickup directory.

Comment: replace "messaging quote" with "messaging queue"

Answer (score 0):

Whenever an operation like is hingent upon an event, there is always the possibility something will go wrong.

In ASP.NET you can spawn multiple threads and have those threads do the action. Make sure you tell the thread it's a background thread, otherwise ASP.NET might way for the thread to finish before rendering your page:

```
myThread.IsBackground = true;
```

I know you said you didn't want to use system process or scheduled tasks, but a windows service would be a viable approach to this as well. The approach would be to use MS Queue, or save the actions needing to be done in a DataBase table. Then have a windows service check every minute or so and do those actions.

This way, if something fails (Email server down) those emails / actions can still be done.
They will also be recorded for audit's (which is very nice to have).

This method allows you're web site to function as a website while offloading these tasks to another service. The last thing you need is for multiple ASP.NET processes to be used up waiting for emails to send. let something else handle that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do this.

You could store enough details about the message in the database, and write a windows service to loop through them and send the email.  When the user submits the form it just inserts the required data about the message and trusts the service will pick it up.  Almost an email queue which you said you didn't want, but you're going to end up in a queue situation with almost any solution.

Another option would be to drop in NServiceBus.  Use that for these kinds of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I typically compile the message body and store that in a table in the db along with the from and to addresses, a subject, and a timestamp indicating when the email was sent. Then I have a background task check the table periodically and pull any that haven't been sent. This task attempts to send each email and updates the timestamp accordingly. One advantage of storing the compiled message body up front is that the background task doesn't have to do any processing of context-specific data, and therefore can be pretty darn simple.